# Flash Video Capture Card

Tags: flash

I would like to do some video capture through flash.  Is there a good video capture card I should use? Or will any do?

Comment: Your question is better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much any card which has a video input can do capturing, if the host drivers support (and allow) it. Flash won't care what kind of card it is, as long as the card appears as a proper video capture device to the host platform.